# Adding a detailed description to the nausea card（Carekit)

Tags: swift, carekit

In my carekit application, the nausea card task(which actually shows the fecal incontinence(便失禁))is displayed as follows.

```
var query4 = OCKEventQuery(for: date)
            query4.taskIDs = ["nausea4"]
            
            if let nauseaTask = tasks.first(where: { $0.id == "nausea4" }) {
                
                print("Nausea task found")
                let viewSynchronizer = OCKButtonLogTaskViewSynchronizer()


                let nauseaCard = OCKButtonLogTaskViewController(
                    query: query4,
                    store:self.store, 
                    viewSynchronizer: viewSynchronizer
                    )
             
                
                listViewController.appendViewController(nauseaCard, animated: false)
```

I want to add an image and a description on the screen that appears when I click the” → “part, but I didn't know the class that does this. Anyone have any good ideas?　Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in the discussion in carekit issue #702, so I'm attaching the link.

https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKit/issues/702